# A better way to define $\bigcap S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In books on set theory $\bigcap S$ is defined for $S \neq \emptyset$ by taking some arbitrary member $x \in S$ and separating those elements from $x$ that belong to every memebr of $S$. It leads to a problem of what to do if $S = \emptyset$. This case is handled separately by defining $\bigcap S = \emptyset$.

Why don't they just define $\bigcap S := \{x \in \bigcup S |$ $x$ belongs to every member of $S\}$. Then if $S$ is empty, $\bigcup S$ will be empty and there is nothing to separate from it. If $S$ is not empty, then the result is the same as if we used the previous definition.

The only drawback of the new definition is that we need *the axiom of union* to get $\bigcup S$. But it is a standard axiom.

Comment: The problem is that the simple characterization $x\in \bigcap S\iff \forall s\in S\colon x\in s$ does not hold any more; it is replaced by the less handy $\iff (\exists s\in S\colon x\in s)\land (\forall s\in S\colon x\in s)$. Btw, I usually see $\bigcap \emptyset $ left undefined instead of specifically defined to be empty. - The latter has ugly consequences such as $S\subseteq S'\not\rightarrow \bigcap S'\subseteq \bigcap S$.

Comment: Usually the sets being considered live in some universe $X$. It's natural to have „empty intersection“ = „everything (considered)“. So $\bigcap ∅ = X$. If there is no other universe, then $\bigcap ∅$ is universal class which is not a set.

Comment: Somewhat related: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/unary-intersection-of-the-empty-set, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188/empty-intersection-and-empty-union,
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/unnecessary-property-in-definition-of-topological-space and other posts shown there among linked questions.

Comment: Another problem with $\bigcap \emptyset = \emptyset$ is we would no longer have $\bigcap (A \cup B) = \bigcap A \cap \bigcap B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's ever correct to define $\bigcap \emptyset=\emptyset$.  One always expects that taking an intersection of more things should get you a smaller result.  (The set of big red ugly expensive things is a subset of the set of big things.)  That is, $$\def\S{\mathscr S}\text{if $\S\subset \mathscr T$ then $\bigcap \mathscr T\subset \bigcap \S$}.$$  But having $\bigcap\emptyset = \emptyset$ would spoil that.  So that answers one of your questions, which is why we don't do that.   I find it hard to believe that any serious text for set theory would do as you say and make $\bigcap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

In set theories with a universal set $V$, one takes $\bigcap \emptyset= V$ for that reason; then we have $\emptyset\subset \S$ for all $\S$ and also $\bigcap \S \subset \bigcap \emptyset = V$, as we would hope.  In set theories without a universal set, most notably ZF, one leaves $\bigcap \emptyset$ undefined.

In ZF there is no axiom of intersection that corresponds to the axiom of union; one uses the specification axioms to define intersections.  Recall that this means that for any predicate $\Phi(x)$ and any set $X$ we can construct $\{x\in X\mid \Phi(x)\}$, the subset of $X$ for which $\Phi$ holds.  Let's see how this goes in this case.  We want to take the set of all $s$ that are in every $S$ that is an element of $\S$.  But to use the specification axiom schema, we can't take this condition by itself; we have to attach it to some set $X$ and use it to select the desired subset of $X$.

So in ZF the best we can do is $$\{x\in X\mid \forall S\in \S . x\in S\}$$  for some set $X$, which we might agree to abbreviate as  $$\def\S{\mathscr S}\bigcap_{(X)}\S.$$   This is the subset of $X$ whose elements are in every element of $\S$, or we might call it the intersection of $S$ "taken relative to $X$".  If there were a universal set $V$ then we could take the intersection relative to $V$ and be done (and note that then $\bigcap_{(V)}\emptyset = V$) but ZF has no universal set.

But it should be clear (or you can take it as an exercise) that no matter what $X$ is, if $S\in \S$, we have $$\bigcap_{(X)}\S \subset \bigcap_{(S)} \S.$$  From this it immediately follows that for any $S, S'\in \S$, then $$\bigcap_{(S)}\S = \bigcap_{(S')}\S$$ so it doesn't matter which element of $\S$ we take the intersection relative to.

This shows that when $\S$ is nonempty, there is a unique maximal relative intersection of the elements of $S$, which we can abbreviate as simply $\bigcap \S$.  And since $$\bigcap_{(X)}\S = X\cap \bigcap \S$$ the relative intersections weren't getting us anything interesting, and we lose nothing to forget about them.  In particular it doesn't matter if we take $X = \bigcup \S$ as you suggest, because the intersection is the same regardless.  So we may as well take the simpler definition.

On the other hand, when $\S=\emptyset$, we have $\bigcap_{(X)} \S = X$, which is rather useless, so we lose nothing to forget about it.

Comment: Carl Mummert and Arturo Magidin agree in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/unary-intersection-of-the-empty-set%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B that some authors do make $\bigcap\emptyset=\emptyset $, to my amazement.

Comment: Another potential problem with defining $\bigcap \emptyset=\emptyset$ would be no longer having $\bigcap (A \cup B) = \bigcap A \cap \bigcap B$.