# Does $\bigcup\emptyset$ equal $\bigcup\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any collection of sets $A = \{A_i\ : i \in I \}$, define

$$\bigcup A = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$$

Question: Is the following true?

$$\bigcup \emptyset = \bigcup \{\emptyset \}$$

The right-hand side, using the definition, is simply the empty set.  However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to interpret the left - hand side.  I'm guessing the fact that the left-hand side is the empty set follows "vacuously", but I'm not too certain.

Can somebody help me understand?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188/empty-intersection-and-empty-union

Comment: I think the RHS is $\{\emptyset\}$, not $\emptyset$; while the LHS is just $\emptyset$. Remember, $\cup A_i = \{x : x\in A_i$ for some $i.\}$, hence $\emptyset$ is an element of the RHS.

Comment: @thyde641 The symbol on RHS denotes taking the union of all elements in the set, so it would be just the empty set, not the set containing the empty set.

Comment: I have changed the title, so that it better describes the question. If needed, edit/improve it again. It is useful to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 13):

The union $\bigcup\varnothing$ is empty vacuously (the union of no sets).

The union $\bigcup\{\varnothing\}$ is empty because $\bigcup\{x\}=x$, and in this case $x$ is the empty set.

So yes, they are equal.

Note that this is not a trait unique to the empty set. Take $\omega$ for example, the first infinite ordinal. $\omega$ has the property $\omega=\bigcup\omega$, so we also have $\bigcup\omega=\bigcup\{\omega\}$. The same is true for any limit ordinal.

Answer (score 2):

The union on the RHS is the empty set: if $x$ is in the union, then $x\in \emptyset$, a contradiction, thus there are no elements in the union.

The union on the LHS, as a union over an empty indexed collection of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $I=\emptyset$ is also the empty set: if $x$ is in the union, then there must be some index $i\in I$ with $x\in A_i$. Since no such $i$ exists, there are no elements in the union.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that (by definition, see, for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28mathematics%29#Arbitrary_unions))
$$x\in\bigcup \mathcal S \Leftrightarrow (\exists S\in \mathcal S)x\in S$$
So $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$, since for no element $x$ there exists $S\in\emptyset$ fulfilling $x\in S$. (Simply because there is no $S$ in $\emptyset$.)

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$To expand on the other answers, here is a slightly more detailed proof that both sets are empty, but for different reasons.

For the first set, we calculate its members $\;x\;$ as follows:
$$\calc
x \in \bigcup \emptyset
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\bigcup\;$}
\langle \exists V : V \in \emptyset : x \in V \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\emptyset\;$}
\langle \exists V : \text{false} : x \in V \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify}
\text{false}
\endcalc$$

For the second set, we similarly calculate for all $\;x\;$:
$$\calc
x \in \bigcup \{\emptyset\}
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\bigcup\;$}
\langle \exists V : V \in \{\emptyset\} : x \in V \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\{\ldots\}\;$}
\langle \exists V : V = \emptyset : x \in V \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: one-point rule}
x \in \emptyset
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\emptyset\;$}
\text{false}
\endcalc$$

Therefore both sets are empty, and therefore they are equal.