# Difference between closed under pairwise intersection and closed under finite intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does it mean by pairwise intersection? Is it the same as finite intersection?

First, it is trivial that if a set is closed under finite intersection, it is closed under pairwise as well. Now, I show a set closed under pairwise intersection is also closed under finite intersection.

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under pairwise intersection. Let $A, B, C$ be given such that they are in $\mathcal{S}$. Then $A\cap B\in\mathcal{S}$. Since $C\in\mathcal{S}$, $(A\cap B)\cap C\in\mathcal{S}$. Induction gives us that any finite intersection is also in $\mathcal{S}$.

So it seems like they are really the same concept, right?

Comment: I tried to google, no luck...

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly valid: indeed these two concepts are equivalent. This is why you don't find anything about "pairwise intersection": it's a non-standard way of saying "finite intersection".

Comment: @Crostul Would you please post it as an answer please?

Comment: Yes, they're the same: if a set is closed under an binary operation pairwise, then it's closed under all finite combinations under that operation.

Answer (score 1):

The operations are *not* equivalent, because closure under **empty** intersections does *not* follow from closure under pairwise intersections. However, an empty intersection is clearly a finite intersection.

[$\pi$-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system) are families of sets which are closed under pairwise intersections (hence all *non-empty* finite intersections). However, they do *not* have to be closed under empty intersections, hence do not have to be closed under all finite intersections.

Your [induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411551/understanding-closed-under-finite-intersection-notation) only works to show closure under *non-empty* finite intersections. In particular, it's not possible to induct "backwards" from $n=1,2$ to $n=0$ (empty intersection).

The question and answers on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188/empty-intersection-and-empty-union) explain empty intersection better than I can.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946307/if-a-collection-on-omega-is-closed-under-finite-intersections-then-can-we-co).

Comment: I know this seems like obnoxious pedantry, but the distinction is emphasized heavily, for example, in the definition of lattice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(order_theory)#Finite_completeness Namely a lattice has to be closed under _non-empty_ finite meets and joins, but not all lattices are bounded, i.e. also closed under the empty meet and the empty join.