# Question on proof of the statement: An Algebra is closed under finite unions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, algebraic-topology

I wish to show that an **algebra** is closed under finite unions.

Can I do it using induction on the number of unions performed over the elements of my algebra say $\mathcal{A}$ instead of induction on the number of elements in $\mathcal{A}$ involved in the union such as the one used in

[understanding closed under finite intersection notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411551/understanding-closed-under-finite-intersection-notation/2411567?noredirect=1#comment6069021_2411567)

and in

[Is strong induction necessary in proving that an algebra is closed under finite union?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936815/is-strong-induction-necessary-in-proving-that-an-algebra-is-closed-under-finite) ?

Is it more appropriate to do induction in the number of unions, instead on the number of elements?

Comment: What kind of algebra are you talking about? And what sets are you taking he Union of?

Comment: @TomGrubb I am talking about **algebra** $\mathcal{A}$ that is a collection of subsets of a set $X$ that satisfies the following properties: (i) If $A\in\mathcal{A}$ so is $A'$ and (ii) If $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal{A}$ so is $A\cup B$.

Comment: Yes, you should use induction over the number of elements in the union. Don't forget to deal with the special case of the empty union.

Comment: @MeesdeVries do you mean that I cant use induction over union? Thanks in advance

Comment: What...? I said you *should* to induction over the number of elements that appear in the union.

Comment: @MeesdeVries is it better than the induction over the number of unions performed? Why? Sorry for my follow up questions.