# Is the phrase "closed under intersections" correct here?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

In a measure theory course, we are given the following:

*Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $R$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. We say that $R$ is a $\pi$-system if it is closed under intersections, i.e. if it has the property:
If $A \in R$ and $B \in R$ then $A \cap B \in R$.*

This definition makes sense, but I'm not curious more generally about the meaning of "closed under intersection". Here I understand it to mean exactly what we have after the "i.e.", but should it mean more? We can have the empty intersection, which gives the whole of $X$, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188/empty-intersection-and-empty-union):

Which breaks what I understand to be the definition of a $\pi$-system. I'm not sure whether that makes the terminology "closed under intersections" incorrect, though. Does it? In general, if we say that, I'd have thought we should really mean closed under the empty intersection too, but is that something I should be concerned about?

Comment: In practice it probably doesn't make any difference.  The main use of $\pi$-systems is in the $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma, and you would get an equivalent statement whether or not you defined a $\pi$-system to be "closed under empty intersections" (i.e. to contain $X$).  However the definition certainly should have said "closed under *finite* intersections" or something to that effect, since infinite intersections are definitely not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between arbitrary intersections (take a set, which could be empty or infinite, and intersect all the elements, usually denoted with a $\bigcap$ in front of the set) and pairwise intersections (take two elements and intersect them, usually denoted by the regular $\cap$ between the two sets).

My guess is that they're using the pairwise one (that's what their "i.e." is saying anyways), without stating it explicitly.

Comment: Certainly infinite intersections are not intended to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

"X is closed under binary (unary/whatever) function $f$" in all the contexts  which i saw until now in measure theory is

**Let $a, b \in X$, then $f(a, b) \in X$**.

Being it intersections, union, countable unions, completions etc.