# Is every element a union of some subset, for a set closed under arbitrary unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $A$ satisfying $Y\subset A\implies \bigcup Y\in A$ for any $Y$.
Now, I intuitively expect that any set $X\in A$ will satisfy $X = \bigcup Y$ for some $Y\subset A$. But I am not completely sure, and I have no idea how to prove or disprove it.

Any help?

Comment: Let $Y=\{X\}$, a singleton family.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Sorry, I don't get you example/counterexample.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I now get it. Thanks!

Comment: You've gotten a good Answer, but you might want to note that the union over an empty family of sets is by convention [the empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\in A$, then $X\subset A$
whence $X = \bigcup \{X\}$.

Comment: Oh! How could I not get this!